# Replace AtomicBoolean by primitive type when only the get() and set() methods are used?

Tags: java, atomic, atomicboolean

My code contains some `AtomicBoolean` fields. Only the `get()` and `set()` methods of these fields are called.

Can the types of these fields safely be replaced by primitive boolean?

I mean, assignment and access operations of primitive booleans are atomic operations in Java. And from that point of view I cannot see any reason to use `AtomicBoolean` in my case.

In my understanding `AtomicBoolean` would only make sense if methods like `compareAndSet` are used, that combine a comparison and access. Am I wrong about that? Could you explain why?

Comment: Too broad without showing the code in question, but the general answer is no.

Comment: Are you accessing the fields from different threads?

Comment: there's two types of race conditions: check-then-act and read-modify-write.  your problem will be the former if you replace `AtomicBoolean` with a primitive boolean.

Comment: Yes, I'm accessing them from different threads

Comment: @mre Why should this happen? The code is not using `compareAndSet()` or any similar method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition

Comment: @mre Your link explains the check-then-act problem. But why should this be a problem in my case since access and assignment operations of primitive booleans are always atomic in Java and my code does not contain any checks?

Comment: @eztam, no one reads the field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Atomic variables are described as *"better volatiles"* in *Java Concurrency in Practice* (see section 15.3). Here is an extract from this book:

> The atomic variable classes provide a generalization of `volatile`
>   variables to support atomic conditional *read-modify-write* operations.
>   `AtomicInteger` represents an `int` value, and provides `get` and `set`
>   methods with the same memory semantics as reads and writes to a
>   `volatile int`.

Applied to your case this means that if you're using only `get()` and `set()` methods of [`AtomicBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html), they can be safely replaced with read-writes to `volatile boolean`.

`volatile` is needed to guarantee that all threads will see *up-to-date* value of the variable. Back to *Java Concurrency in Practice* (section 3.1.4):

> When a field is declared `volatile`, the compiler and runtime are put on
>   notice that this variable is shared and that operations on it should
>   not be reordered with other memory operations. `Volatile` variables are
>   not cached in registers or in caches where they are hidden from other
>   processors, so a read of a `volatile` variable always returns the most
>   recent write by any thread.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. Could you explain why primitive boolean without volatile is not working in my situation? Or could you describe a scenario that could lead to problems when using primitive boolean in my case?

Comment: @eztam `AtomicBoolean` is passed as a reference. If you pass a `boolean` to two threads they will no longer have a shared value.

Comment: @eztam. The only scenario which could lead to problems using primitive `boolean` is using it in _check-then-act_ operations. In this case you should use `AtomicBoolean` (or use synchronization).

Comment: @PeterLawrey Good point! But I'm just talking about accessing fields from the same class. The AtomicBooleans are not passed anywhere.

Comment: @Peter. Primitives are shared in the same way as references. You just need to make sure you've declared your primitive as `volatile` so all threads will see up-to-date value.

Comment: @eztam Do you mean adding my last comment to the answer?

Comment: I meant the first comment. But why should `volatile` be needed in that case since read and write operations to boolean variables are always atomic https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Comment: @eztam Volatiles do NOT guarantee _atomicity_. They only guarantee _visibility_.

Answer (score 2):

> Can the types of these fields safely be replaced by primitive boolean?

Simple primitive `boolean` is not the same as [AtomicBoolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) (which provided atomic access in a multi-threaded environment).

But, the safe replacement alternative could be using `volatile boolean` which would also provide the atomic access, but I suggest you keep the `AtomicBoolean` as is (because it provides additional API methods, in case if you might it in future).

Comment: Thanks, the difference between primitive boolean and AtomicBoolean is clear to me. But could you explain why it is not possible to replace them in my individual situation?

Comment: Can you tell me why do you want to do that? I mean what exactly you are expecting out of it? Because already the access is atomic (as you are using `AtomicBoolean`), so why do you want to change the existing behavior?

Answer (score -1):

The answer is no. You can find the reasons here [Why can't AtomicBoolean be a replacement for Boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941526/why-cant-atomicboolean-be-a-replacement-for-boolean)

Comment: That post is about opposite replacement: Replacing `Boolean` with `AtomicBoolean`.

Comment: Yes. But when you read the provided answer, it is explain that AtomicBoolean is a separate class designed for concurrency purposes. So AtomicBoolean is thread safe. So you cannot replace it by primitive boolean.

Comment: In the case you don't want to use AtomicBoolean in your code, you can use a primitive boolean, but you should handle the thread safe property yourself by using synchronisation.

Comment: Reading and writing primitive `volatile boolean` will also be thread safe. `AtomicBoolean` is useful for _check-then-act_ or _compound_ operations which should be performed atomically (e.g. `getAndSet()` or `compareAndSet()`).

Comment: @PavloViazovskyy I agree with that. But as I explained, the code is not using `getAndSet()` or `compareAndSet()` or something similar. The question is just about the case when only `get()`and `set()` is called.

Comment: @eztam, the caller of `get()` is not guaranteed to get the most up to date value.